# Multiple Vuex applications running in a single page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

It is indeed possible to have more than one Vue instance running at the same time on a page. But is it possible to have multiple instances of Vuex stores running alongside each other?

In the Vue dev-tools (Chrome and Firefox alike) it looks like the store that is loaded first get's privileged, as I can only see it's state and getters in the Vuex tab.

Is there a solution to this problem or do I have to resort to implementing Vuex modules in order for it to work?

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/430

Comment: I guess, there is a central store and inside it, you can have multiple store with the use of `vuex` modules.

Comment: @str: Okay, I was almost beginning to suspect that there was a bug in the dev-tools. Not a lot of action on the ticket last couple of months. Guess the best idea is to disable the store in the other apps while debugging.